# Mock view helper in Yii2 in PHPUnit test

Tags: php, yii, yii2, mocking, phpunit

I want to test a specific controller action in Yii2 framework. This action render view file that use helper yii\helpers\Url:

```
Url::toRoute('page')
```

When unit test call this view I have error:

```
yii\base\InvalidArgumentException: Unable to resolve the relative route: vendor/bin/. No active controller is available.
```

Test:

```php
<?php

use app\modules\user\controllers\UserController;

class UserControllerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testActionIndex() {

        Yii::configure(Yii::$app, [
            'components' => [
                'user' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\User',
                    'identityClass' => 'app\modules\user\models\User',
                ],
                'request' => [
                    'class' => 'yii\web\Request',
                    'cookieValidationKey' => 'abc',
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        $controller = new UserController('user', Yii::$app);
        $result = $controller->run('index', []);
    }
}
```

How can I mock method Url::toRoute in view to avoid this error?

Comment: You can't really mock the static methods without changing the source. There are some tricks how to do that but they are all based on indirect calling of static methods in source. The unit tests are not actually designed to test controller's action, it's better to use functional tests for those. If you absolutely have to unit test controller's action you can probably extend your UserController and override the render() method to return some dummy string instead of actual rendering.

Comment: I don't know about Yii framework, but you can use \Mockery::mock('alias:ClassWhichContainsStaticMethod')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Url` helper uses `Yii::$app->controller` for resolving relative routes. You need to set `Yii::$app->controller` before you call your action:

```
Yii::$app->controller = new UserController('user', Yii::$app);
$result = Yii::$app->controller->run('index', []);
```

Alternatively you may avoid this problem using absolute routes:

```
Url::toRoute('/mymodule/mycontroller/page');
```

Although it is quite impractical, since you will need to repeat the same route in many places.